# Lastest Version of ReactJS and LeafLet.Shapefile Not Work, only display blank page

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, shapefile, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

I'm currently working on ReactJS GIS and referring to this sample [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-zipped-shapefiles-to-a-react-leaflet-map-e7cr0?file=/src/Shapefile.jsx). But when I update the latest version of React and dependencies is not work, no error message displayed on the console. What wrong. I've also test in my local computer, the result is same (not work) what happen?

The demo:
[image]

After update the dependencies:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things that have been changed:

1. React has changed to 18.x. You should replace in index.js all the code

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

   import App from "./App";

   const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

   root.render(
     <App />
   );
   ```
2. react-leaflet has moved to version 4.x which has breaking changes:

map ref is received via a ref and a useState hook and no need for `map.current` or `map.current.leafletElement`. Also `Map` comp has been renamed to `MapContainer`

```
 const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    map.setView([34.74161249883172, 18.6328125], 2);
  }, [map]);

<MapContainer
      center={position}
      zoom={13}
      style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      ref={setMap}
    >
```

3. mapRef in MapContainer's child components is received via

   ```
   const map = useMap();
   ```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-zipped-shapefiles-to-a-react-leaflet-v-4-x-and-react-18-0-2-nlruc1?file=/src/Shapefile.jsx:195-219)

Comment: Thank you @kboul, but I have to tell you ....the css code <code>import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";</code> is still generate an erro

<code>WARNING in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css)       
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning</code>

Comment: You 're welcome. This error has to do with your custom app configuration which I am not aware of.

Comment: Hello @kboul, one more thing....in your sandbox...everything is work, why in my local...is not show the border? just show the map. Anything I missed ? thanks, just curious

Comment: Hi kboul, I just found the problem due to the coordinates system using in my shapefile, my coordinates system is UTM.